# Select only those records that have multiple value in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have only those rows that have multiple rows in the same table. For example see below image.
[image]

In the above picture you can see 2 highlighted columns one is for useid(u_id) and second is for product id (product_id).

So you can see user id of 7 has multiple product like (78,40,44,45,53) and  user id 9 has multiple products like (79,75,79) same like user id 40 has multiple products.

so want out put like if particular user have multiple products then it will display 'multiple product' in product name column instead of display all product name.
[image]

above picture display all product but i need to display 'multiple product'     message instead of all products if particular user have multiple products

I have used following query but not getting result that i want .

```
SELECT *
FROM orderlist
WHERE product_id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM orderlist
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Better to handle this in your application code, get sorted results from database and show user name only once if there are multiple products for a user

Comment: Please show us the exact tabular output you are expecting here.  What you want is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Whatever query you're currently using to produce that result is fine. You can do a simple analysis of the resulting array to determine whether multiple products are associated with a given user. You could even do this in JavaScript, with (almost) no change to your existing PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the `JOINS` after aggregation

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN c.Counts > 1 THEN 'Multi' ELSE o.ProductName END ProductName 
FROM 
(
     SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) Counts
     FROM orderlist
     GROUP BY product_id
)c INNER JOIN orderlist o ON o.product_id = c.product_id
```